# understanding the graphs of tau vs R in an RC circuit, and tau vs 1/r in an RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, time-constant

from my understanding, in a circuit like this one:[image]

in order to calculate tau, you can use the inductor's value divided by the resistor's value. as the resistance (or impedance, in A/C). As R changes value, tau does as well. plotting tau and 1/R results in a linear realtionship. experiemntally, the time to reach  63% max current is also tau.

Similarly, in an RC circuit. like this one:[image]

you can measure time to 63% max current and get tau. however, the linear relationship is now tau vs R!

I don't understand how that works exactly. I read something about Laplace transformations, but I would be lying if I said I understood them even a little. How exactly does the relationship between tau and R work in these cases?

Comment: We usually use a DC source with a switch to analyse the time-constant of LR and RC circuits. SE supports HTML entities. You can use `&tau;` to get the symbol (but it doesn't work in the comments).

Comment: The difference between C and L comes down to the different differential equations inherent to the element.  For a Capacitor, I = C dV/dt, but for an inductor, V=L dI/dt.

Comment: or, to take it another step, an inductor is a short at DC and open at high-freq, but a capacitor is a short at high freq, and open at DC.

Comment: Where did you get this \$\tau\$ from? That source would explain how R,C and R,L are related...

Comment: @ScottSeidmanI have heard of that shorting before, but I never really understood how or why. I've looked over the equations, but I think there is something I am missing, as I still don't understand the relationship.

Comment: @Transistorthanks for the markup info. I was always shown this analysis using a square wave from an A/C source, I haven't done a D/C analysis

Comment: @Huisman tau was found from 1- e^-1, giving us 0.632; the time to reach 63% of the mac current is tau. theoretically, values come from tau = RC and tau = L/R.

Comment: @Rambunctiouslad Where did you find the equation 1-e^(-1/RC)?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Capacitors store energy in the electrical field and inductors store energy in a magnetic field.  See https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vvHazxjqq3Ib5VBqHGOLbU96FYpXV76R for a basic explanation.

Comment: @huismann from the equation to determine charging voltage. V(t) = v0(1-e^-t/RC)

Comment: @ScottSeidman thank you, I will take a look at that resource

Answer (score 1):

Think of the time constant of a circuit as the amount of time it takes for all the transient stuff to die off.

Now, look at the two circuits in the steady state: 
   For the cap circuit: The voltage across the capacitor is V and the current through the capacitor is zero.
   For the inductor circuit: The current through the inductor is V/R and the voltage across the inductor is zero.

For the capacitor circuit, doubling the resistor will make the charging current half, and so it will take double the time to reach steady state. So, the time constant is proportional to R. 
For the inductor circuit doubling the resistor will make the final current half as much, as so it will take half the time to reach steady state. . So, the time constant is proportional to 1/R.

Comment: No. The time taken for a transient to dissipate is normally taken as \$5\tau\$

Answer (score 0):

Laplace domain is useful in order to analyze circuits.

Let's think about Ohm's Law of a resistor in Laplace domain:

\$ V(f)=Z(f)*I(f)=R*I(f) \$

where Z(f) is the impedance that depends from frequency.

In Laplace domain, something similar is defined for capacitor and inductor.

Capacitor:
\$V(f)=Z(f)*I(f)=\frac{1}{j*2*pi*f*C}*I(f)\$

Inductor:
\$V(f)=Z(f)*I(f)=(j*2*pi*f*L)*I(f)\$

As you can see, the difference between Z inductor and Z capacitor is that the second one is a fractional number.

When you define the equation for calculating tau, you will get different tau values for this reason.